# Use vb.net module in c# project

Tags: c#, vb.net, reference, module, include

I would like to use a vb.net module in my c# project. I compiled the vb.net module and I added reference to its dll in c# project, but I can't see it in c# project. The module is public, I tried to write its namespace (dll file name) before the module name, I tried to manually insert `using moduleNameSpace`, I checked that both projects have the same destination framework (4.5 without client profile), but I still can't see it. I have no idea about what I should do further.
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

A portion of vb.net module:

```
Namespace GestioneSetupFile
Public Module GestioneSetupFiles
   Private Const TAB_POS As Short = 30
   Dim Testo, Paragrafo As String
   Dim PtrParagrafo As Integer

   Public DEFAULT_APP_DIR As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
   'Public DEFAULT_APP_DIR As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\BTSR\PC-LINK NEMO"

    Public DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR As String = DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\Config"

    Public Sub CheckConfigDir()
    'Verifica la presenza della cartella Config
    'Se non esiste la crea e per compatibilità con le versioni precedenti ci copia dentro tutti i files .cfg e .dat che trova
    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR) Then
        'Dim NomeFile As String
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR)
        'NomeFile = Dir(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\*.cfg")
        'While NomeFile <> ""
        '    'My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\" + NomeFile, DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR + "\" + NomeFile)
        '    'per compatibilità con vecchio (se reinstallato) non sposta ma copia i file
        '    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\" + NomeFile, DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR + "\" + NomeFile)
        '    NomeFile = Dir()
        'End While
        'NomeFile = Dir(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\*.dat")
        'While NomeFile <> ""
        '    'My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\" + NomeFile, DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR + "\" + NomeFile)
        '    'per compatibilità con vecchio (se reinstallato) non sposta ma copia i file
        '    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\" + NomeFile, DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR + "\" + NomeFile)
        '    NomeFile = Dir()
        'End While
    End If
End Sub
End Module
End Namespace
```

And this is my call in c# project:

```
using System;
/*Others using*/
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using GestioneSetupFile; //Compile error

namespace UltraFeederControl
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       private void updateConfigFile()
       {
           GestioneSetupFiles.CheckConfigDir();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: why can't you take the code from the vb.Module and convert it to it's C# equivalent and create a Class in C# or Extension Method that emulates the same functionality.. if you are not sure how to do that.. then post the Modules code signature and it's functionality and one of use could point you in the right direction in regards to converting the code..

Comment: Did you search in the object browser?

Comment: Without a (minimal) definition of your VB module, your attempted usage in C#, and the compiler error you're receiving, no one is going to be able to give you a direct answer.

Comment: @MethodMan I didn't convert it because I thought it was faster to include it. Not knowing visual basic I would lose too much time, however now it has become a matter of principle. Looking on google seems so simple to implement a vb module and now I would understand why I can't.

Comment: @RickS In the object browser I see the reference empty

Comment: are you putting `using Microsoft.VisualBasic` in your header.. as well as adding the actual .dll or reference to the assembly in your  project..?

Comment: @MethodMan referencing a .net assembly written in VB.NET should work fine in C# without having modification to the C# project.  Once the VB.NET (or C#) source is compiled, any .NET project should be able to reference it.  Keeping in mind things like runtime versions, etc.

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, I'm doing it, even if I think it's not necessary to add `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

Comment: well I have referenced many .NET Assembly's written in VB and I had to add the using Microsoft.VisualBasic at the top of the .cs file that's why I had mentioned it..

Comment: @PrestonGuillot the error is `Type or namespace 'GestioneSetupFiles' does not exists in namespace 'GestioneSetupFile'; probably missing an assembly reference`
Now I try to add a minimal portion of the module in the question

Comment: it sure would benefit us all if we could see the code along with how the NameSpace is defined .. that would limit in the number of comments / suggestions

Comment: Stab in the dark, but in the VB code, can you add a namespace around the module declaration?

Comment: Use Object Browser to see what the full name is.  VB provides a default namespace in Project Properties, any others are appended.  I have to note that there is only one line of code there, should be easy to convert.

Comment: @Matthew I tried to add a namespace around the module and call with it in c# but it doesn't work

Comment: @Plutonix In object browser I see only the reference name, empty. If I use the reference name as namespace it doesn't work. I also tried to add a namespace around the vb module and call it, but it doesn't work. I posted only a portion of module, it's longer than one line

Comment: can you edit your code to show how your are using the name space.. what is the namespace of the C# coded project I converted the code for you to use C# but I am curious to see how you are using namespace

Comment: Cannot repro.  Import the DLL, `using ClassLibrary1` (default name space VB assigned), `ClassLibrary1.FooBar()` shows up in intellisence.

Comment: @MethodMan is this what you asked me?

Comment: yes but I would like to see how the VB module has the namespace defined in your code just edit your original question so as to not confuse others

Comment: @Plutonix I don't know what to tell you, but I have nothing in Intellisense even if I manually insert a namespace in module (and so it must be that)

Comment: Load the VB project.  Go to Properties=>Application.  Look at Root Namespace.  that is what you must import/using.  Append any `Namespace{}` you added in the code.  I would predict is it not `GestioneSetupFile` as the root namespace.

Comment: also `using GestioneSetupFile;` this is incorrect you can't add a Method to the using ...it should be a namespace or class name.. what's the name of the namespace.. [VB.NET NameSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx)

Comment: @Plutonix I see `GestioneSetupFile`, the namespace I'm trying to use from the first moment

Comment: Since you specify a namespace in code, VB **appends** it to the root namespace it provides.  It is not like C#.  The real NS is going to be something like `ClassLibrary1.GestioneSetupFile`

Comment: much easier to convert the code to C# personally .. avoid the headaches in my opinion..

Comment: Even if I remove my namespace I still see `GestioneFileSetup` there and `ClassLibrary1` isn't recognized

Comment: `ClassLibrary1` was an example, a placeholder! Open the VB project as described above and fetch it from Properties

Comment: As I said in Properties -> Application -> Root Namespace I see only `GestioneSetupFile` (and I removed excplit namespace in module code) and it doesn't work. I'll try to convert it if there aren't other solutions

Comment: Try changing the Module to a Class in VB and make the Sub and everything else Shared. 

Another thing to try is look at the Project Properties of the VB project and make sure that the assembly namespace is what you think it is. [Edit: Now I see a previous comment that you've done that]

Comment: I would name the namespace in your VB module the same as the one in your C# project

Comment: ...which means for the code above, it should be `using GestioneSetupFile.GestioneSetupFile` .  I mix these guys all the time and usually remove the VB default NS so it works more like C#

Comment: I would never name my namespace close to the Method name that's way too condfusing and opens up the door for issues like you're seeing currently Vitto

Comment: `Vitto` if you seriously want the VB code converted I can help you do it ...in the mean time I have provided some good links that help explain the differences down in the answer below.. inside the editor on this page keep in mind the the `'` is a comment in VB as well as in this page so where you see `//` in the code sample I provided I can uncomment as well to show actual functionality

Comment: @dwilliss I tried to change it into a Class with Shared methods but it still doesn't work. I also tried to give it the same namespace of c# project

Comment: I created a new module file where I copied the code and now it works! I have no idea about what was the problem, but the old file doesn't work, this one works. Thank you very much to all who have tried to help me

Answer (score 1):

here is the C# converted code that you need.. make sure if you add this to a Class that you put the

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GestioneSetupFile
{
    public static class GestioneSetupFiles
    {
        private const short TAB_POS = 30;
        static string Testo;
        static string Paragrafo;

        static int PtrParagrafo;
        public static string DEFAULT_APP_DIR = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath;

        public static string DEFAULT_APP_DIR = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\BTSR\\PC-LINK NEMO";

        public static string DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR = DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\\Config";
        public static void CheckConfigDir()
        {

            if (!My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR)) 
            {
                string NomeFile = null;
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR);
                NomeFile = FileSystem.Dir(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\\*.cfg");
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NomeFile)) 
                {
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\\" + NomeFile, DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR + "\\" + NomeFile);
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\\" + NomeFile, DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR + "\\" + NomeFile);
                    NomeFile = FileSystem.Dir();
                }
                NomeFile = FileSystem.Dir(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\\*.dat");
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NomeFile)) 
                {
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\\" + NomeFile, DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR + "\\" + NomeFile);
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(DEFAULT_APP_DIR + "\\" + NomeFile, DEFAULT_CONFIG_DIR + "\\" + NomeFile);
                    NomeFile = FileSystem.Dir();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[To see Hot Root NameSpace Work in VB vs C#.NET](http://spiderinnet1.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/vbnet-root-namespace-vs-c-default-namespace.html) take a look here and you will see how to fix your problem otherwise the converted portion is what I have started for you is here..

Comment: Thank you, but I posted only a portion of module, and however I would like to comprend why I can't simply include it

Comment: perhaps you need to fully qualify the namespace I would love to see what the namespace of the C# project looks like.. then name your Visualbasic one to be the same as well or to access it you need to do it but it's fully qualified namespace does that make sense

Comment: Vito you can look at this link as well [VB.NET Namespave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx)

Comment: There are times where it just isn't practical to convert old code.  Yes, it would be nice to start a project to rewrite everything, but if you have multiple clients using code that uses a library that has the module in it, you would want to be able to reference it from new C# code in the mean time rather than having duplicate code, and hopefully in a way that will allow you to rewrite that module code later without having to change the new C# code.   There's nothing wrong with this question in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way to do it, but in my case the module in question was part of a VB project that also had a class library that I could reference.  I just created a method in that library that called the function in the module.  This gave me access and I didn't need to duplicate code.  When we rewrite it, I should not need to change my C# code.  It was a little different because I was accessing a function within the module, but here I THINK it would look like this, but you get the idea:

```
Public Class MyLibrary
    Public Shared Sub GestioneSetupFiles()
        GestioneSetupFile.GestioneSetupFiles()
    End Sub
End Class
```